# Exposing objects to Fastreport

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe, fastreport

I'm using FastReport (evaluation version) mainly to print invoices and quotes. I'm trying to maintain a separation between my data sources and the application logic, so I'm wondering if there is an easy way to expose Delphi objects directly to FastReport. Currently, I'm resorting to custom data sources but this is a lot of manual fiddling.

Basically, I want to take my already instanced TInvoice object and print it using FastReport.

Has anybody implemented a common ancestor class or interface to expose Delphi objects as data sources to FastReport (or another reporting tool)?

**Edit:** I'm using Delphi XE.

Comment: What version of Delphi, I have something for 2010 that uses the new RTTI.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Using Delphi 2010 or later you can use the code located here:

http://code.google.com/p/robstechcorner/source/browse/branches/rttiwork/ObjDS.pas

It can be used in the following way:

```
//typically created and declared someplace else
cds : TClientDataSet; 
Invoice : TInvoice;

var
  Mapper : TDataSetMapping;
begin
  Mapper := TDataSetMapping.Create(cds);
  Mapper.Value := Invoice;
  // CDS is now populated with the values stored in Invoice
end;
```

Comment: Ooo... this is very nice!  I'm surprised I haven't noticed that library before.

Comment: Sounds intriguing -- does it knows how to handle collections?

Comment: If an object implements GetEnumerator as specified for the FOR IN loop, then it will load the members of the list as individual rows in the dataset.

Comment: So--- does it knows how to handle collections? *<grin>*. I'll check this when I get home.

Comment: It depends on the implementation of collection.   But most collections it will know how to handle.

Comment: I've tried this solution. Looks like a hint in the right direction -- but I need to create some non-visual component that can be dropped in a form and allows to assign some other component, so I can get the exposed properties in design-time. I've never created design-time components before, looks like a nice thing to learn.

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for paid one, I have something for you.
Support simple types, memorystream class as memo field, and sub-object. Work from delphi 7 and xe. Something below nature. Can be used binding for editing also

```
{$M+}
TSubInfo = class
publish
  property AMem: TMemoryStream read ... write ....
  property ADat: TDateTime read ... write ....
end;

TInvoice = class
publish
  property AInt: Integer read ... write ...
  property AStr: string read ... write ...
  property ASubInfo: TSubInfo read ... write ...
end;
{$M-}

var
  DataSet: TObjectDataSet; // is decendent from TDataSet
  Invoice: TInvoice;
begin
  Invoice := TInvoice.Create...
  DataSet := TObjectDataSet.Create...;
  DataSet.BindObject := Invoice;
  DataSet.Active := True;
  .....
```

Contact me as apz28  at  hotmail dot com

Comment: No, I'm not. Besides, asking somebody to contact you at a hotmail address isn't the best way to make business. Thank you for the offer, thought.